# Update abpuser and change only the length of Name column from 64 to 250

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, abp

I'm trying to update the length of the column "Name" and "surname" from 64 to 250
when I open ModuleExtensionConfigurator.cs in domain.shared layer
I found this method

```
private static void ConfigureExistingProperties()
{
    /* You can change max lengths for properties of the
     * entities defined in the modules used by your application.
     *
     * Example: Change user and role name max lengths

       IdentityUserConsts.MaxNameLength = 99;
       IdentityRoleConsts.MaxNameLength = 99;

     * Notice: It is not suggested to change property lengths
     * unless you really need it. Go with the standard values wherever possible.
     *
     * If you are using EF Core, you will need to run the add-migration command after your changes.
     */
    IdentityUserConsts.MaxNameLength = 256;

}
```

After I did this change and add migration nothing happened and empty migration generated
How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ConfigureExistingProperties method in projectModuleExtensionConfigurator in your domain.shared add following code

```
        AbpUserConsts.MaxNameLength = 250;
```

I hope this solve your question